# как искать по unordered_map

Tags: c++

Народ, я запхал в

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Movie>> MovieByTitel
```

объект Movie, который имеет значения такие как Название, год выпуска, режиссёр. И нужно, чтобы программа спрашивала "Найти Фильм:  "  и можно было бы ввести первые пару символов названия фильма и программа выдавала бы все фильмы в названиях которых есть комбинации этих символов. 
Вообщем не знаю как сделать match по буквам в названии и вытащить все эти фильмы из map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартными способами быстро это в `unordered_map` не сделать. Я так понимаю вам нужен либо обычный `map` и использовать в нём `lower_bound` либо же писать *бор* (словарное дерево) самому.

`unordered_map` использует хеш-таблицы поэтому информация о первых буквах недоступна. Вы конечно можете пройти по всей коллекции но с таким же успехом можете `vector` использовать.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто не совсем разобрался еще в этом. Тогда сделаю вектор. Можете подсказать как сделать такой поиск по вектору ?)

Comment: @Владимир вас совсем не заботит производительность?

Comment: абсолютно. Это домашка из вуза. Главное, чтоб работало )

Comment: @pavel: Дайте человеку сначала хоть как-то решить проблему :) Хотя конечно `lower_bound` — правильное решение, имеет смысл понять его и разобраться.

Comment: @Владимир `for (string name : Collection) if (!name.compare(0, find.length(), find)) cout << name;`

Comment: @pavel спасибо ))

Comment: @Владимир: Если ваша проблема решилась, не забудьте отметить ответ галочкой (слева).